# How to tune PasswordReset custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am newbie in azure ad b2c custom policies. Currently I am trying to understand is it possible to redefine LocalAccount PasswordReset custom policy from starterpack in the way as on the picture:[Desired journey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZejA.png)

Requirements are

- 1st screen: exclude separate SendCode button making Continue button responsible for both: sending code and moving to the next screen if the code was sent;
- 2nd screen: lock email, provide VerifyCode field, Continue button responsible for both: verifying the code and moving to the next screen if the code was verified;
- 3rd screen: standard screen with newPassword, reenterPassword and Continue button as in the starterpack

I really hope you can help

Comment: Yes you can achieve that flow. Example [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/split-email-verification-and-signup) on how to split pages as you describe.

Comment: The first step of split-email-verification-and-signup policy looks like the same as  localaccount resetpassword.  The 1st screen provides all functions to validate email and button Continue to complete email validation going to the next screen.
My question is "Is it possible to separate send code and verify code between two screens?" I'd like to send code pressing Continue button on the 1st screen and verify the code pressing Continue on the 2nd screen.

Comment: Is there any chance to call AadSspr-SendCode getting code sent on the 1st screen and AadSspr-VerifyCode getting the code verified on 2nd screen?

Answer (score 0):

•   Yes, you can surely create the password reset setup as you desire in the diagram attached in your post. For this purpose, you will have to edit the **‘Trustframeworkextensions.xml’** file with that given in the link as below: -

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/commit/7669af06637550739e845b7ad42211a3a412658d

In the link above, the **‘SplitEmailVerificationAndSignup_TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml’** file must be uploaded and used in the `Azure AD B2C Identity Experience Framework` custom policies list. In this file, you will have to edit the **‘Technical Profile’** section with ID **‘LocalAccountSignUpWithReadOnlyEmail’**. In that, you will have to remove the **‘OutputClaim’ for ‘objectId’, ‘displayName’, ‘givenName’, ‘surName’, ‘newUser’ and ‘authenticationSource’ from the said ‘TechnicalProfile’**. Else, let all other details be the same and then upload the policy and try testing the user flow. It will give you the same result screen as expected by you.

Also, ensure that the **‘SplitEmailVerificationandSignup.xml’** file is also uploaded such that the references for other policy files are found correctly.

Comment: Probably I didn't provide my requirements clearly enough. I'm trying to understand is it possible to imitate VerificationControl DisplayControl behavior with AadSspr-SendCode & AadSspr-VerifyCode calling them on different orchestration steps. I was able to answer the question partially positive built-in this profiles to ValidationTechnicalProfiles. When I click Continue the profiles are executed and I have sending code on the 1st page with moving to the 2nd page and verifying on the 2nd with moving to the next page.

Comment: Why partially? Because on the second page I need also SendNewCode button and appropriate behavior. So, my additional question is it possible to call AadSspr-SendCode with custom button on the 2nd page correctly having the same behavior as in VerificationControl?

Comment: Can this be implemented with SubJourney any way?

Comment: I've implemented required behavior using one extra control - dropdown list - and calling validation profiles conditionally based on actual value of the dropdown list. So, choosing sendNewCode in the list and pressing Continue I run a validation profile that call AadSsspr-SendCode. After that next validation profile throws exception and I have a new code sent staying on the same screen. Only a problem that I have error message shown and as I understand this is a problem which I can't solve. Probably someone can help with advice.